# Symfony2 ignore certain route

Tags: php, symfony, routes, slim

I have the following situation:

I'm running a Symfony 2 project on a server with the route www.homepage.de.

Every request to a random route  on www.homepage.de will be routed to my Landing Page.

Now I want to integrate another project, an API build with Slim PHP and Swagger UI, into this Symfony 2 project. I cloned the project into the /web directory of the Symfony2 project to gurantee access to it.

But now every request I want to do to www.homepage.de/api fails because the Symfony 2 project wants to handle the request and can't find the route. Is there a possibility to tell Symfony2 to ignore every request that is send to the www.homepage.de/api route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all don't add anything to web folder of your application. Just create two applications in different folders. If you want the API to be accessible through the same domain but just with `/api` you cen use either mod_alias or mod_rewrite to achieve this.

In your current solution it is not Symfony that is intercepting your requests. Take a look at your .htaccess. This is where the magic happens. You can always modify rewrite rules to intercept all `/api` requests and redirect them to your application but I would still suggest to keep those projects apart.